# How to wait for the get request to finish in React?

Tags: reactjs, django, api

I'm new to react and need to represent a JSON array in a table. The format of the array is [{"transaction_amount": 39.98, "transaction_date": 2020}, {...}]. This works when I assign this fixed data to a constant but if a request it from props, it isn't rendered.
The below code doesn't work:

```
<App transactions={this.state.transactions} />

const App = props => {
   const data = props.transactions;
  const columns = [
        { title: "#", data: "id" },
        { title: "Transaction Amount", data: "transaction_amount" },
        { title: "Transaction Date", data: "transaction_date" },
  ];

 return (
    <>
      <h5 className="mt-2 mb-4 text-center">Recent Transactions</h5>
      <DataTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

but if I replace data with:

```
const data = [{"transaction_amount": 39.98, "transaction_date": 2020}, {...}]
```

then everything works fine. I'm guessing that the error is that the first time the page is rendered, props.transactions is empty. How can I fix that?

This is the function for the get request:

```
 load() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments?type=company',{
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')}
        })
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({failed:false});
             setTimeout(() => {
                        this.setState({ transactions: res.data, loading: false });
                        }, 500)

          })
    }
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling your load function?

Comment: I've switched it instead of ComponentDidMount because I was trying something out but I'll revert it back now. I'm calling it in the constructor with this.load = this.load.bind(this);
         this.load();

Answer (score 0):

Only render when data loaded

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      transactions: [],
      loading: false
    };

  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.load();
}

 load = () => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments?type=company',{
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')}
        })
          .then(res => {
            
              this.setState({ transactions: res.data, loading: false });

          })
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.transactions.length > 0 ?
         <App transactions={this.state.transactions} /> : 
         null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: I've tried this but it still doesn't work. I've also tried setting this in the component's return functions but it also doesn't work.

Comment: The data is not being sent on time i.e. I can console log it and it shows up without showing an empty array first but for some reason I'm still getting the error "TypeError: currentRows.map is not a function"